# too much brightness in some sides of an icosahedron

Tags: objects, light

This is the first time I ask something in this site. Thanks for reading me.

What I want is to reduce the brightness of the surface of an icosahedron -some sides. Because what I want to do later is write in each side of this object and I suppose that if exist so much light in a written side therefore it wouldn't be readable.

It is possible that all the faces can have the same intensity or energy of light? And in this case, not with the brightness signalized with red in the image, but with the same level of light signalized with blue. This is the link of sketchfab: https://skfb.ly/6ArvI. And this is a screenshot of the object in Sketchfab.

[image]

Another problem it is that when I render the object what I see in Blender its not how I see it in Sketchfab, so I need to upload in that site a exported file to know how will show finally.

[image: screenshot of the object in sketchfab]

File to download: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FdoxP63h0TlEnBUdfUCQlkOumzFQbuaV/view?usp=sharing

Sorry if I'm imprecise in this question. Thanks.

Comment: While links and files may be helpful questions should stand on their own, your Sketchfab link doesn't work and to answer your question one must now download a file to understand what you want. Please describe the issue and add images to your post so it is answerable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DuarteFarrajotaRamos. I edited the post -fixed the sketchfab link- and added images. I hope that it will helpful for the readers.

Comment: "*what I see in Blender its not how I see it in Sketchfab*" Obviously Blender couldn't possibly predict what some random site will render your model like. Not sure how Sketchfab works these days, haven't used it in quite a while, but sounds like you need to adjust your lighting in the website model viewer, not inside Blender